# Test for handling list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want it to be working like this so then `d` disappears etc.

```
?- remove_last_item([a,b,c,d], L).    
L = [a, b, c] ?
```

Does anyone know how to do this as I got this line 
but what other line should I add to this so then the
above can be achieved.

Comment: I hope you've read my whole answer, not just copied the code. Please show us that you have: write out a predicate which removes one item before last, in a list. Call it `remove_before_last(A,B)`. What is the simplest case there (i.e. the first clause of the predicate)?

Comment: i understood it what do you want me to do

Comment: @WillNess: having other users do tests is not part of this website's rules or etiquette, is it?

Comment: @larsmans I'm learning. It felt like this was a homework, but still, the question was so basic it was clear the OP was making their very first steps with Prolog, so I've shown a complete solution this time. Then, to make sure they wouldn't just copy the code, I asked of the OP to do an additional exercise (not a test).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Prolog usually, to understand the question is to have your answer already. So you need to define a predicate, `remove_last_item(A,B)` such that `B` is `A` without the last item. So what *is* list in Prolog? Like in Lisp, it is recursively defined on top of pairs, with special symbol - empty list - signifying the "end of list".

What does that mean? A pair, `'.'(A,B)`, obviously has two parts. The list `[a,b,c,d]` is then encoded as `'.'(a,'.'(b,'.'(c,'.'(d,[]))))`. This can also be written as `[a|[b,c,d]]`, or `[a,b|[c,d]]`, or `[a,b,c|[d]]`, or `[a,b,c,d|[]]`. Here `a` is what's known as "head" and `[b,c,d]` a "tail" or "rest" of the list `[a,b,c,d]`.

So now we just write down what we want our predicate to say, from the simplest case up:

```
remove_last_item([_A],[]).
remove_last_item([A|B],[A|C]):- B=[_|_], remove_last_item(B,C).
```

It reads, "removing last item from a singleton list leaves us with an empty list; removing last item from a list of more than one element means removing the last item from the rest of the list, coming after its head".

***edit:*** Another way to look at it is by "starting from the top": writing down some equivalency "law", which the predicate must follow:

```
remove_last_item(L,R):- is_list(L), is_list(R), same_head(L,R),
                        tail(L,L1), tail(R,R1), 
  remove_last_item(L1,R1).
```

We still don't *"know"* what `remove_last_item` *"does"*, we just wrote down an equivalency law that it must follow, right? But then it becomes the very definition itself that we're after. Fleshing out all the suggestive names, it becomes the (familiar)

```
remove_last_item(L,R):- L=[A|L1], R=[A|R1], remove_last_item(L1,R1).
```

So now we can recognize this as [*structural recursion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) over lists, and just add a termination clause, to add some "substance" to it.

Comment: Using !/0 is unfortunate here since it removes valid solutions for example in the query remove_last_item(Ls0, Ls). In addition, I recommend to think in terms of relations and call the predicate for example list_without_last/2.

Comment: @mat these are two distinct use cases. Perhaps each one is better served with its own predicate. The OP demonstrated their intention with the name suggestive of imperative reading. The pure relational generative predicate would be better served by its own definition, like the one you suggested, less optimal in cases of processing concrete data.

Comment: @mat but you're right, in general. The definition in my answer would still be wrong though, even if cut were removed: if the order of clauses were to be exchanged, your example would loop. The real problem is that the two clauses were not mutually exclusive. I initially did that to have the code shorter for the OP, but it was a bad decision. I'll edit it shortly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
?- append(L, [_], [a,b,c,d]).
```

Observe that `[_]` represent a list with a single, arbitrary element, so this query asks "which list `L` gives `[a,b,c,d]` when we append a single element list to it?"

Comment: so when i am writing my rule what else should i put on because i have remove_last_item(List1, List2).

Comment: @user1232622: you should figure that out yourself. I'm not doing your homework for you.

Comment: its not homework if just a problem from a prolog book that i want help with but doesn't matter anymore

Comment: @user1232622 why doesn't it (matter anymore)? If you've started this *quest*, see it through. Explore all possible solutions, and learn something new from each. Here you were presented wth the solution which does almost exactly the same thing as the "hand-made" code in my answer, but using the readily available `append`. While it's good to write your own code while you're learning the language, when you start really coding, you should use this approach, not mine. So *do* figure out, how to write down your predicate to have it use this code. As in, "to do *this*, it means doing *that*" thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to get prolog to do the recursion.. this says 'find all Items in the list where the index of the list item does not equal the index of the last item of the list (whose index is the same as the length of the list).  (when using nth1 anyway.. nth0 would not work...

```
rli(List, Res) :-
    length(List, Y),
    findall(Item, (nth1(Idx, List, Item), not(Idx =:= Y)), Res).
```

Comment: This algorithm has quadratic complexity, while the problem can easily be solved in linear time.